# Javadoc missing documentation for top-level package

Tags: javadoc

My project is structured in the following way:

```
core
  -> receiver
    * Receiver.java
    * package-info.java
  -> reactive
    * ReactiveStream.java
    * package-info.java
  * package-info.java
```

`core` is the top-level package, containing two subpackages `receiver` and `reactive`. All of these packages contain a `package-info.java`.

I generate the javadoc using the javadoc gradle task. The documentation is generated as expected, but the `package-info.java` documentation for the top-level `core` package is lost, as the package does not contain a class, resulting in the package not being listed. Only `core.receiver` and `core.reactive` are listed in the package overview of the docs and i can not find any way to access the package documentation for `core`.

Is there a way to force javadoc to include the package and its documentation? The actual project is a lot bigger and i would like to have a hierarchical documentation for developers that just want to look through the packages of the library.